Traffic is too loud to hear you
I have made up the sentences below.
(1) The traffic is too loud to hear you. We should go to a quiet place to have a talk.
My non-native friends think "too loud to hear you" doesn't sound right. (2) below is their revision.
(2) The traffic is too loud for me to hear you. We should go to a quiet place to have a talk.
Is the first sentence in my example (1) wrong?

"Wrong"? I think it would be understood. But (2) is better.

Your friends are right. :)

Both are correct. The first sentence would sound more natural perhaps like .. "the traffic here is too loud to hear you!!"

With such loud traffic, I would assume my listener would have trouble hearing too, and I would probably choose fewer (and louder) words. "Traffic is too loud to hear you" would be just fine, even just "It's too loud to hear you".

I don’t see it here yet, so I just wanted to comment that idiomatically I’d say “I can’t hear you over the traffic” to communicate this idea.

@Fattie Where else would the traffic be, but here? "The traffic in Shanghai is too loud to hear you, let's go into the cafe on 42nd street?" :)

hi @Kaz true enough, you couldn't hear Shanghai from here   :)  The fact is though it sounds VERY "foreign language speaker" if you say something like "Traffic is too loud to hear you".  In English it seems for a natural native sound, many things need to be specifically decorated. If we were in my kitchen and I suddenly uttered "floor is slippery" you'd assume I'm Hindi or German.  I'd utter "this floor is slippery" - even though as you point out it's evident I am talking of the floor at hand (at foot?), not some other floor. There are any number of examples of this.

Sometimes, often, we interpret sentences based on assumptions about the real world.
If I said, "Mary is too loud to hear you", it would be unclear whether I mean that I cannot hear you or that Mary cannot hear you.
But "Traffic is too loud ...", well traffic doesn't hear anybody, traffic doesn't have ears, so I must mean that it is too loud for me to hear you.
In cases like the first, we can add words to clarify. "Mary is too loud for her to hear you" versus "Mary is too loud for me to hear you", for example.
In the second case, adding "for me" might enable a listener to understand the sentence a fraction of a second more quickly. But it's not strictly necessary.

I have to agree. In the real world, such utterances are instantly understood. The sun is too bright to read my book. The water's too cold to swim.

The main point here is that traffic doesn't hear anythng. +1.

Wait a few years until we have AI in vehicles

@Lambie - Basil Fawlty famously thought that his car, reluctant to start, would benefit from a sound thrashing.

As a native speaker (American) I'd even shorten it to "Traffic's too loud to hear."

@MichaelHarvey If your computer is not doing what you want, try yelling at it. "Show me the file, you stupid computer!" The computer will then be ashamed for failing to do its job and will perform as desired. :-)

@Jay I have long wondered whether someone attempting to Google a nasty computer problem they're having would get more focused results by peppering the query with foul language, on the premise that other people with the same problem are likely to use foul language to describe it too. But I've never scientifically tested that hypothesis.

@JudithJones or replace "traffic" by, say, "television" or any other modern appliance that ~~spies on you~~ can be controlled by voice.

While it is probably true that native English speakers would assume the intended meaning and overlook any seeming grammatical error, I have an issue with this as an answer because we could literally just say this in response to every question on here. I mean, if a non-native said "me hungry!", we'd know what they meant, but that doesn't mean it's good English. So are we here to answer questions about learning English, or are we here to assure people that, if they speak gobbledygook, they will be understood anyway? Do the people asking questions want to speak English well, or just 'get by'?

@Astralbee There's a difference between "it's an error but you can figure out what was meant" and "it is often valid in English to omit superfluous information". One could say of any sentence that it does not include all information that might possibly be relevant. To clarify, I am NOT saying "the sentence is grammatically incorrect because it does not specify who or what cannot hear but you can figure it out." Rather, what I am saying IS "in English it is often not necessary to specify who or what is being referred to when it is obvious from context or knowledge of the real world.

English allows such infinitival clauses that seem to be missing a subject:

It's too cold to go swimming.
It's too cold to swim.
The water is too cold to go swimming.
It's too smoky to see clearly.
It's too smoky to see anything clearly.
The picture's too blurry to identify the people.
The ice is too thin to go skating
The soup is too spicy to eat.

Absent an explicit subject they're understood to mean that the action expressed by the verb is itself impossible, inadvisable, undesirable, etc, given the extreme or excessive condition in the main clause.
P.S. Compare a similar complement with rather the opposite meaning (too vs so):

The picture's so blurry to anonymize the people.


I would say only your fourth example mirrors the OP's sentence -- it's the only one with an object. But for me it clinches the argument -- the OP's sentence is valid.

I'll add another one and toss in some lagniappe for good measure.

There's an implied, elided, subject in all of these examples (except the last).  You can insert "for me" or "for anyone".

Your new example doesn't work for me at all! You can rescue it by inserting as between blurry and to, but it's still a bit clunky. Or replacing so blurry with blurry enough. But as it stands I think it's an error.

@Spencer: for me is neither a subject nor an object here.

@TonyK It's informal, but I don't think it sounds wrong. It answers the (implied) question Why is the picture so blurry? "The picture's so blurry [in order] to anonymize the people," but [in order] can be left out since it's an informal context.

@QuackE.Duck: If that's the intended meaning, then OK. But TimR says it has "rather the opposite meaning", which it doesn't under your interpretation -- the original (too blurry) has no notion of intent.

@TonyK   How do you feel about "The picture's so blurry in order to anonymize the people" and "The picture's that blurry to anonymize the people."  ?

Yes, but those mean something else! They're definitely not opposite in meaning to your fourth (now sixth) example.

@TonyK  What I meant was that too blurry  expresses excessive degree whereas so blurry expresses (desired) degree, and the too clausal complement expresses what is not possible and the so clausal complement expresses what is achieved.   I hear these sorts of constructions (i.e. the "blurry" ones) all the time but they do strike my ear as a tad marginal.

Your first sentence is perfectly normal vernacular English. It isn't strictly 'correct', and some people would be slightly bothered by that - I would use the second sentence in, for example, a job interview, where I want to sound like I pay attention to my grammar.

The sentence is fine in informal English. It omits naming the subject doing the hearing. From a formal viewpoint, the grammar allows for the interpretation, "the traffic is too loud for the traffic to hear you". But that interpretation (1) wouldn't be taken, since the obvious implied subject is the speaker who is having trouble hearing; i.e. for me to hear you.
Furthermore, by omitting for me, the speaker makes it clear that the traffic is too loud for anyone to hear you.
The grammatical pattern is similar to the one in, "it's too dark to see", which is 100% correct. While we can say "it's too dark for me to see", not only is that unnecessary, it is also too specific, because the original sentence means that it's too dark for anyone to see, not me specifically.
There is no possible weird interpretation in "it's too dark to see", because "it's too dark" doesn't name a specific, concrete subject like "the traffic". There is just the word it serving as a grammatical subject (called the "expletive subject"). The interpretation that this expletive it is the one doing the seeing is semantically too nonsensical to be applicable; it could not be interpreted along the pattern of "he's too distracted to see".
But you can see how in the sentence, "he's too distracted to notice you", the unmistakable semantic subject doing the noticing (or failing to notice) is he. This sentence could not possibly mean "he's too distracted for me to notice you"; it makes no sense. Yet, notice that "the traffic is too loud to hear you" has exactly the same pattern as "he's too distracted to see you"; that's why some English speakers may be taken aback by it.
I think most speakers would not be taken aback by it if they heard it in the situation, in real time, uttered by someone who obviously is having trouble hearing someone else; it's only when you isolate it and analyze it that the strange interpretation ("the traffic cannot hear you") becomes more noticeable.

As others have said, both are natural phrases you would expect to hear from a native English speaker, but they have slightly different meanings because the subject/emphasis is a little different.
Saying "The traffic is too loud to hear you" implies that the traffic is generally too loud for anybody to hear them, while "The traffic is too loud for me to hear you" leaves room for it being an issue for you specifically, but may not be for others.
It's a bit like saying "This food is too spicy" vs "This food is too spicy for me" - the first is a general statement about the dish, the second is a statement about your preferences in relation to the dish.

Many good answers already.  To summarize the key points for you:
Sentence 1

is perfectly comprehensible to native English speakers
sounds more natural in spoken conversation (shorter in a noisy environment and leaves out unnecessary words)
native English speakers generally leave out unnecessary words

Sentence 2

sounds like non-native English speaker trying to get it right by being precise
in writing, maybe the second is preferrable? No, not even then in this case, as Jay explains


In constructions that use "too [x] to [y]" the usual inference is that the subject has an attribute (x) that is preventing it from doing something (y) or having it being done to it. For example, "it is too hot to handle" means that 'it' is unable to be handled itself. So it's odd to use this construction in the way you have - it sounds like the traffic is unable to hear.
You should instead say something like:

I can't hear you because the traffic is too loud.

You need something like the conjunction to logically join the problem (you can't hear the other person) to the cause (the noise of the traffic).

Another common idiom to express the idea is "I can't hear you over the traffic, . . ."  (leaving out "noise" after "traffic" because it's understood)
